# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.mksquad.swapit/at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.MainActivity}?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, runtimeexception

I am developing new app but when I run project in debug mode I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.mksquad.swapit/at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2976)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at at.mksquad.swapit.data.sources.auth.AuthSourceFirebase.getUidOfLoggedInUser(AuthSourceFirebase.kt:18)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.features.auth.AuthManager.getUidOfLoggedInUser(AuthManager.kt:28)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.data.repositories.UserRepository.getUid(UserRepository.kt:30)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.utils.UserUtil.createNewUser(UserUtil.kt:17)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.data.repositories.UserRepository.loadUser(UserRepository.kt:90)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.SharedViewModel.<init>(SharedViewModel.kt:12)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.SharedViewModelFactory.create(SharedViewModelFactory.kt:14)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.MainActivity.getSharedViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.MainActivity.prepareViews(MainActivity.kt:765)
        at at.mksquad.swapit.ui.screenflow.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:194)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)


        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

below following My MainActivity.kt  https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/2a369fcbb2138cb9e25c0855514dc162 code

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake I have run debug mode but run step by step but it did not show anything but exception point out in following code in AuthSourceFirebase.kt

```
object AuthSourceFirebase {
    fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null
    }

    fun getUidOfLoggedInUser(): String {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid // this line cause exception
    }

    fun loginUser(
        activity: Activity,
        mail: String,
        password: String,
        loginCallback: AuthManager.UserLoginCallback
    ) {
        Timber.d("Starting process to login..")
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            mail,
            password
        ).addOnCompleteListener(activity) {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                loginCallback.onCallback(null)
            }
        }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                val error = e as FirebaseAuthException
                Timber.d("Error logging in, code: %s", error.errorCode)
                loginCallback.onCallback(
                    LibFirebaseErrors.getErrorFromErrorCode(
                        activity,
                        error.errorCode
                    )
                )
            }
    }

    fun registerUser(
        activity: Activity,
        mail: String,
        password: String,
        registrationCallback: AuthManager.UserRegistrationCallback
    ) {
        Timber.d("Starting process to register..")
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            mail,
            password
        ).addOnCompleteListener(activity) {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                registrationCallback.onCallback(null)
            }
        }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                val error = e as FirebaseAuthException
                Timber.d("Error logging in, code: %s", error.errorCode)
                registrationCallback.onCallback(
                    LibFirebaseErrors.getErrorFromErrorCode(activity, error.errorCode)
                )
            }
    }

    fun sendPasswordResetMail(
        activity: Activity,
        mail: String,
        resetPwMailCallback: AuthManager.UserResetPwMailCallback
    ) {
        Timber.d("Starting process to reset password..")
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail(mail)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    resetPwMailCallback.onCallback(null)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                val error = e as FirebaseAuthException
                Timber.d("Error sending mail, code: %s", error.errorCode)
                resetPwMailCallback.onCallback(
                    LibFirebaseErrors.getErrorFromErrorCode(
                        activity,
                        error.errorCode
                    )
                )
            }
    }

    fun logUserOut(context: Context){
        UserRepository.deleteUserLocal(context)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
    }
}
```

I have tried my in order to avoid nullpointer exception following way it did not work

```
fun getUidOfLoggedInUser(): String {

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid == null){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        }
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting looks like a regular Null Pointer exception. According to the exception stack trace here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at at.mksquad.swapit.data.sources.auth.AuthSourceFirebase.**getUidOfLoggedInUser(AuthSourceFirebase.kt:18)**
    at at.mksquad.swapit.features.auth.AuthManager.getUidOfLoggedInUser(AuthManager.kt:28)
    at at.mksquad.swapit.data.repositories.UserRepository.getUid(UserRepository.kt:30)
```

and

```
fun getUidOfLoggedInUser(): String {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid // this line cause exception
}
```

Make sure your currentUser is not null. Please check if Firebase authentication is processed and current user session is active.

Update your code like this:

```
**fun getUidOfLoggedInUser(): String {

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser == null || FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid == null){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() return
    }
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
}**
```

Comment: I have changed for other code like this fun getUidOfLoggedInUser(): String? {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid // but I have changed that code implementation in multiple places what is your suggestion
}

Comment: how can I implement following function in real code Make sure your currentUser is not null. Please check if Firebase authentication is processed and current user session is active. can you explain what you said in coding sample

Comment: @sashabeliy !! means currentUser cannot be null, please change currentUser!!.uid to currentUser?.uid and route user to login screen for authentication if currentUser is null.

Comment: please check my updated code I already implemented as you told or please redit your code